# Duplicate closed question should be reversed for this case

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

This question got closed
[Does Wolverine still have his adamantium claws after the change in events?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/21312/does-wolverine-still-have-his-adamantium-claws-after-the-change-in-events) because its duplicate of [Questions after watching X-Men days of future past](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/20078/questions-after-watching-x-men-days-of-future-past).

But i think this should be reversed. 1st thing the second question is having ,<strike>three</strike> now two question together. And its not even of good quality. So we are closing a better contender with a poor question.

For me the solution should be reopen the 1st question and remove the Adamantiam part from the second question. What you guys think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sold on the idea - I think @JohnSmithOptional would need to transfer his answer though.